# I need to find number of duplicate elements in a list in java

Tags: java, list, duplicates

```
public static int countDuplicate(List<Integer> numbers)
{
    int total_count=0,i,j;
    Collections.sort(numbers);
    for(i=0;i<numbers.size()-1;i++)
    {
        int count=0;
        for(j=i+1;j<numbers.size();j++)
        {
            if((Integer)numbers.get(i)==(Integer)numbers.get(j))
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        i=j-1;
        if(count>0)
            total_count++;
    }
    return total_count;
}
```

My code is working fine but in certain test cases while giving exam it showed wrong output . I don't know why, I tried several things but could not get to the solution . Suggest me how to improve it .

Comment: " in certain test cases... it showed wrong output " Please give details on those test cases or on the reasons why you do not know details.

Comment: "My code is working fine" What makes you think so? It seems in contrast to the rest of the question. Please provide the test cases you used to verify "fine" funcitonality. If you are lucky, we can spot the gaps in your test cases and perhaps even deduce what algorithm failure resulted from that. Please turn the shown code into a [mre] which processes your test cases.

Comment: `(Integer)numbers.get(i)==(Integer)numbers.get(j)` you do not need to cast to `Integer`

Comment: How many duplicate elements would you as a human count for "1,2,3,4,1,2,2"?  I count 2 (2 different values occur more than once). I.e. please clarify what the definition of "number of duplicates" is.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code is too complex to solve problems like this. Improvements that I suggest:

1. You should not manipulate the increment values in for loop. If you are going to do this, use while. `i=j-1;`
2. There is no need to sort values if you are going to search all of the list which you are doing right now.
3. you set the count = 0 before loop started and if you find any duplication you are incrementing count and next step you are sets count to 0 again. There is no need to do this.
4. If you are breaking the second loop, you can not find any more duplication. For example

1-2-1-5-7-8-1-2-1 in this case first 1(index=0) duplicates with 3 of 1 (index=2,index=6,index=8). But if you dont want to add all duplications for same number, you can delete the numbers or stores them into a Set to check if this number is used or not. Below is the example of how many duplication (includes same numbers) exist in List.

```
public static int countDuplicate(List<Integer> numbers)
{
    int count=0,i,j;
    for(i=0;i<numbers.size()-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<numbers.size();j++)
        {
            if(numbers.get(i).equals(number.get(j))){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using loops what I will do is, Create a set using the list provided and then return the difference between list and set to get the duplicate counts. So the code will look like this:

```
public static int countDuplicate(List<Integer> numbers)
{
    int totalCount=0
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(numbers);
    totalCount = numbers.size() - set.size();
    return totalCount;
}
```